# Compare arrays from different sources and divide values by source

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates, compare

I have some difficulties to get some good idea how to divide values from arrays. For example I have 3 arrays of URLs:

```
$urlsFromA = ['http://www.test.com', 'http://www.example.com', 'http://www.google.com', 'http://www.twitter.com'];
$urlsFromB = ['https://www.test.com', 'http://www.example.com', 'http://www.bing.com'];
$urlsFromC = ['http://www.test.com', 'http://www.google.com'];
```

I need to `foreach` all of the arrays and get to other arrays values which I have duplicates in these start arrays and remove from start arrays if they occurred in the others. 
It is a little hindrance. Because URLs can be difference by 'https' for example but I must treat them like they are the same. So my result will be arrays with URLs named as a Source of this URLs:

```
$urlsFromABC = ['http://www.test.com'];
$urlsFromAB = ['http://www.example.com'];
$urlsFromAC = ['http://www.google.com'];
$urlsFromBC = [];

$dataFromA = ['http://www.twitter.com'];
$urlsFromB = ['http://www.bing.com'];
$urlsFromC = [];
```

In $urlsFromABC I have URL which was in all arrays on start (despite the fact that it is different because of 'https'). In starting arrays ($dataFromA ,$urlsFromB, $urlsFromC) should be URLs that are not duplicated in other start arrays. Maybe someone have idea how can I do this?

Comment: 1) Create a function to 'fix' a URL(eg. replace the `http` with `https`, remove trailing slashes etc.) so you have a clean way to compare two URLs 2) Use [array_diff](http://www.php.net/array_diff) on the different combinations of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a function that changes `https` with `http` like this:

```
function replace($arr){
    foreach($arr as $key => $ar){
        $ar = str_replace('https', 'http', $ar);
        $arr[$key] = $ar;
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

You will call this function like this:

```
$urlsFromA = replace($urlsFromA);
$urlsFromB = replace($urlsFromB);
$urlsFromC = replace($urlsFromC);
```

After that you can play with this two functions: `array_diff` and `array_intersect`.

For example `array_intersect`:

```
$urlsFromABC = array_intersect($urlsFromA, $urlsFromB, $urlsFromC);
```

This will return all the values that exists in all the arrays. You can put how many arrays you want.

And `array_diff`:

```
$urlsFromA = array_diff($urlsFromA, $urlsFromB, $urlsFromC);
```

This will return the values that are in the first array and not in other. You can put how many arrays you want.

You can try how many cases you want. Hope it helps!